# how to add listeners to imageview according to its visibility?

Tags: android

I want to add the listener to an ImageView, when its visibility is invisible.Is it possible to add listeners when the image-view is in invisible state?
Please Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please anyone help me soon.